# Unity 2D - Simple Status UI (scale the distance)

Tags: unity-game-engine, scale

I'm having trouble to implement something like the image attached. Basically, I want the progress of the snail away from the flag to be displayed on my HUD. (take a look at the game window of the editor, upper center)

I'm guessing I just need to scale the distance from the moving object to the flag but I have no idea how. Or I need a new camera for it? Please help!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hey Jim, not sure if you're using C# here or not but you could work out the distance between the two objects, your snail and the flag and use that distance and scale it for your progress bar.

So something like 


`public float Distance {
    get {
      return Vector2.Distance(PointA.position, PointB.position);
}`

Comment: Hi Grinch, yes it's C#. I've already tried a way before I've read your comment but here's how I do it:

1. I made another `camera` only masked to that "mini map" sprites called `terrainMap` and `snailsMap`.
2. Position them nicely on the screen
3. Update the `snailsMap` location via `snails` location. 

:)

Comment: Well without seeing your script I'm only guessing but have you looked at Lerp? Have a look [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html)